# Problem generating random vectors with a randomized linear programming with equality constraints (weird clustering)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, sampling

### Summary

For simulation problems, I need to be able to generate large numbers of random lists of numbers, say $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ (where $n \approx 1000$), subject constraints similar to what one would encounter in a linear programming problem. Optimally, I'd like get solutions distributed uniformly along the solution space, but I just wanted to get things working. I needed to generate them quickly, and so the solution I found was to generate a random set of weights, and then use linear programming to find the set of $x$'s that would maximize the sum. However, when I used a program to output the solution, all the results were clustered around one main result. Why is this? Also, would there be a better way to sample?

### A more concrete set up is this:

$$ \text{Need to generate points: } x_1, x_2, ... x_{1000} \sim U[(??)]$$

Where the $x$'s satisfy:

$$ 0 \leq x_n \leq .005,$$

for some $C$ and all $n$ and:

$$ \mathbf{E}*\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{F},$$

where $\mathbf{E}$ is a matrix with $k \lt n$ rows whose entries: $e_{mn} \sim N(0,1)$ (not totally random, based on real processes, but essentially) and $\mathbf{F}$ is a feasible solution, set by an original solution to the constraints with 200 $x's$ equal to .005. I am trying to match this original solution.  So I solve the following problem:

Let $\mathbf{R} \sim N(0,1).$ Maximize $\mathbf{R*x}$ subject to the preceding constraints.

However, I get "random" solutions that are clustered extremely close to the original solution, within an average euclidean distance of about $10^{-14}$. Any idea why this would be?

### My thoughts

I've been researching the theory behind linear programming and I've realized that if I use my original solution as my "basic feasible solution" after introducing slack variables and such, I get a constraint of the form (using the format of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304099/pivoting-and-simplex-algorithm) answer):

$$\mathbf{A}x = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{N_1} \\ \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{N_2} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_B \\ x_N\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{.005} \end{pmatrix}$$

Where $\mathbf{I}$ is the $n \times n $ identity matrix, $\mathbf{0}$ is $k \times n$, ect. I find that we arrive at the following two equations:

$$ \mathbf{N_1}x_N = 0 $$

$$ \text{and} $$

$$ x_B + \mathbf{N_2}x_N = (.005)$$

The bottom is a standard constraint for linear programming, but the top is extra. Is this what is squeezing my solutions down?